# Linux based Gaming OS

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, steam

What are the Linux based gaming distribution that are available apart from SteamOs? And can that OS be used as live USB OS?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be able to install the Steam client on any major Linux distro. SteamOS is a Debian variant, as is Ubuntu, Mint, etc.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_(software)

most Debian distros support installation on a live USB, though I wouldn't expect awesome performance running it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Manjaro and Pop OS are getting more and more popular in gaming, because these distributions offer easy methods to install drivers. However, if you can install Steam or the-client-you-want-to-use, and a proper GPU driver, just use what you like.

I think most system can run from USB, but it is usually not recommended performance-wise.